# Tutorial for ajax form posting

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, comments, wordpress-theming

I am looking for a short and easy tutorial for posting form data using ajax & POST. More specifically for comments in a custom wordpress theme.

So far I have only found this: http://www.simonerodriguez.com/ajax-form-submit-example/ but the js file is huge so I think there is a lot of bloat (couldn't decipher it all). I've also searched on this site but most threads use jQuery or do not cover what I'm looking for.

Do any of you know a tutorial for this, or could anyone explain the basic code to me?

Thanks a lot for your help and suggestions!

P.S. please do not suggest jQuery as I am not using it and want to learn pure Js :).

Comment: this one is nice: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost.shtml

Comment: @Sebas looks good indeed. I'll take a look at it!

Comment: @Sebas Pot that link as an answer. Perfect content. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've been asked for it... Here is a quite complete link:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost.shtml

Cheers,
S.

Answer (score 0):

```
function initiateRequest() 
{
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
}



function createClearingHouse() {

    parameters = "name=" + document.getElementById("username").value;
    url = EnginePath + "/clearingHouse/persist"
    request = initiateRequest();
    request.open("POST", url, false);
    request.send(parameters);
    if(request.readyState==4  && (request.status == 200)) {         
       alert("success");
    }
}
```

Comment: no this is not part of the code, just i have given heading. i will remove it